# Passing value from Zend controller and fetching it in JS response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a Ajax call like following:

```
$.post("/user/signindo",{'username':username,"password":password},function(data)
{
// this is what I would like to be able to have in my data object, to be able to access these properties and display them once response is there
alert(data.id);
alert(data.username);
alert(data.firstname);
}
```

And this is my Zend controller action:

```
public function signindoAction()
{
// doing something here with the values passed from the view
}
```

The action doesn't needs to return anything basically since it just checks whether the login data is OK. However, what I need to do here is to somehow say in the action that when the response is returned by Javascript, that it somehow fetches the data that I need to work with within the JS script file. How can I do this with Zend framework? Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ban the layout in response. For that, put the following code in your method `Module::onBootstap()` :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $sharedEvents        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $result = $e->getResult();
        if ($result instanceof \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel) {
            // ban the layout only for ajax
            $result->setTerminal($e->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest());
            // To ban the layout for all requests
            // set true : $result->setTerminal(true);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('SbmAjax\Module::onBootstap() the result isn't a \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel');
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your controller build the html response like :

```
public function signindoAction()
{
    // doing something here with the values passed from the view
    return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode(array(
        'data' => ...something,
        'success' => 1
    )));
    // to handle errors return response with 'success' => 0
}
```

Personally I includes all ajax actions in a particular module with as setting for the entire module :

```
$result->setTerminal(true);
```

Comment: Is there any easier way for the ID to be transferred from controller to view?? Perhaps I could store it into the session and then somehow access from the .phtml file ???

Comment: By .phtml file you will not get a JS response.